# Iterate over each value per row in DataTable and compare the value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read and then export a complicated excel sheet using c# and exceldatareader.

Basically, I want to grab specific rows e.g rows 10 to 50 and then iterate over each row and values within the row so that I can compare the values cell by cell. 
E.g I grab the row 10 and it has a fixed number of columns so I need to iterate over each cell in this row, grab the first 4 and then after that if I find a a value other than 0 or null, I grab that value then go some fixed number of rows above that particular cell (where the value other than null or 0 was found) and grab another value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what i have so far. I can iterate over the rows I need and then read the first 4 columns and then for the rest I need to only find the specific cells and then go some steps above that particular cell. What will be the most efficient way to solve this?

```
for (int i=15; i< 25; i++)
        {
            for( int j=1; j< 20; j++)
            {

                if(j < 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i][j]);

                }
                else
                {
                   //if you find any value other than 0 or null grab the position of this cell and then go to a specific cell in top most row.
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: My advice would be to first convert your data structure in memory to be a simple as possible.   Do you have an example of what the data looks like?

Comment: I can't share the original data due to sensitive nature of data but let me create another sheet with random data and I'll post it here.

Comment: Also, What other data structure do you suggest? exceldatareader  only gives the dataset option but I guess I can convert it to IEnumerable or something but that will just complicate things even more

Comment: DataSet/DataTable is fine, however the way the data is displayed in Excel is not always the best when you want to manipulate/query the data.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SDnyyiz e.g for row 7 I'll ignore columns X Y and Z but once I reach column L for row 7 I need to grab the value of this cell and then go few steps above this cell and get Texas and California. Basically I have too many switch or if/else cases here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to play with the indexes like so:

```
for (int i=15; i< 25; i++)
    {
        for( int j=1; j< 20; j++)
        {

            if(j < 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i][j]);

            }
            else
            {
               if (dt2.Rows[i][j] does not equal 0 or null) 
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i-some_fixed_#_of_rows][j]);
               }
               else
               {
                   ...
               }
            }
        }

    }
```

Of course, you also have to check if `i-some_fixed_#_of_rows` does not take you out of bounds.